# Reverse proxy of kibana behind nginx - "upstream prematurely closed connection"

Tags: nginx, kibana

I have kibana listening on `localhost:5601` and if I SSH tunnel to this port I can access kibana in my browser just fine.

I have installed nginx to act as a reverse proxy but having completed the setup all I get is `502 Bad Gateway`. The more detailed error in the nginx error log is

```
*1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream,
client: 1.2.3.4,
server: elk.mydomain.com,
request: "GET /app/kibana HTTP/1.1",
upstream: "http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"
```

My nginx config is:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.fedora.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    index   index.html index.htm;
}
```

My `kibana.conf` file within `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` is:

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name elk.mydomain.com;

    auth_basic "Restricted Access";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade \$http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host \$host;
        proxy_cache_bypass \$http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

This is a brand new Amazon Linux EC2 instance with the latest versions of kibana and nginx installed.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? I feel like it's a simple nginx config problem but I just can't see it.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that the slashes before the dollars `proxy_set_header Upgrade \$http_upgrade;` were a result of a copy-paste from another configuration management tool.

I removed the unnecessary slashes to make `proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;` and reclaimed my sanity.